# Access 2016 - Can I use 1 user-entered parameter to search 2 fields in a query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to help my daughter create an Access 2016 DB to catalog her massive collection of DVD's. For each record, she wants to keep two stars associated with the movie. I suggested fields "MaleStar" and "FemaleStar" but I got "the look" and she told me that many of her movies don't have male stars. (I think we're in trouble guys.) We ended up naming the fields "Star1" and "Star2". Is there a way using query design that I can ask the user for one parameter and have it search both fields? We don't want to make them enter the parameter once for the Star1 field and again for the Star2 field. I'm pretty new to Access so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  use a parameter in one criteria row for Star1 and the same parameter in a different row for Star2.  You'll get one prompt for the parameter value and it will return records with a match in either field.  Furthermore, if you use wildcards in the criteria, you can do partial searches - enter the criteria as  "*" & [name to search for] & "*"     (Not sure it appears correctly - it should be quote-asterisk-quote at the beginning and end)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a many to many relationship instead. That way you can just search the same field and will be able to add as many star as necessary. This link would explain how to do it.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-many-to-many-relationships-e65bcc53-8e1c-444a-b4fb-1c0b8c1f5653?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1